# finish() does not work. Unable to stop an activity after exiting it

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity, activity-finish

I am making a poker game (for a school project) and I am having a problem where after i exit the game (game activity not the app) it keeps running in the background and when you start a new game it messes it up. I have tried every solution in StackOverFlow including: `finishAffinity()`,`finish()`, but none of them worked for me.

The activity extends `AppCompatActivity` and this is one of the solution I tried:

activity:
`
public class OfflineGameTable extends AppCompatActivity {
//defining all views

```
public static BottomSheetFragment blankFragment;


/* Broadcast Receiver for battery */
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
        if (level < 15)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb;
            adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(OfflineGameTable.this);
            adb.setCancelable(false);
            adb.setTitle("Battery alert!");
            adb.setMessage("The level of battery below 15%!");
            adb.setIcon(R.drawable.battery);
            adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

            AlertDialog ad = adb.create();
            ad.show();
            unregisterReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver);
        }
    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_offline_game_table);
    /* Broadcast Receiver for battery */
    this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    //calling all methods
    initViews();
    Game();

}


// boolean to see if the user played
public static boolean played = false;
int i = 0,folded;

//method that runs the game
public void Game(){
    //setting variables
    SetAllNull();
    SetAll();
    folded = 0;
    CheckIfBot0();

    //presenting the user's cards
    playerCard1.setImageResource(players[0].getCard1().getCardPicture());
    playerCard2.setImageResource(players[0].getCard2().getCardPicture());

    //setting starting bet
    currentBet.setText(Bet);

    //setting first cards
    card1.setImageResource(card1Info.getCardPicture());

    card2.setImageResource(card2Info.getCardPicture());

    card3.setImageResource(card3Info.getCardPicture());

    //round 1
    Round();

    new CountDownTimer(55000,1000){

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //round 2

            //setting bet
            currentBet.setText(Bet);
            //setting 4th card
            card4.setImageResource(card4Info.getCardPicture());
            Round();

            new CountDownTimer(55000,1000){

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    //round 3

                    //setting bet
                    currentBet.setText(Bet);
                    //setting 5th card
                    card5.setImageResource(card5Info.getCardPicture());

                    Round();
                    new CountDownTimer(55000,1000){

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            ShowAllCards();
                            CheckWinner();
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }.start();

}

public void WinnerByFold(){
    if(folded == 4){
        if(!players[0].isFolded()){
            Toast.makeText(OfflineGameTable.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //creating and presenting alert dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialog.setMessage("You Won!");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
            AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
            dialog.show();
            players[0].setMoney(players[0].getMoney() + Integer.valueOf(tablePot.getText().toString()));
            playerMoney.setText(String.valueOf(players[0].getMoney()));

            //connecting to firebase
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://holdempoker2-6b7c8-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com");
            //defining path
            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users/"+MainGoogleSignIn.userID+"/Money");

            //set user money
            myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    myRef.setValue(Integer.valueOf(snapshot.getValue().toString()) - Integer.valueOf(tablePot.getText().toString()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
            new CountDownTimer(10000,1000){

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Game();
                }
            }.start();
        }
        if(!players[1].isFolded()){
            Toast.makeText(OfflineGameTable.this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //creating and presenting alert dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialog.setMessage("You Lost!");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
            AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
            dialog.show();
            players[1].setMoney(players[1].getMoney() + Integer.valueOf(tablePot.getText().toString()));
            player2Money.setText(String.valueOf(players[1].getMoney()));
            new CountDownTimer(10000,1000){

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Game();
                }
            }.start();
        }
        if(!players[2].isFolded()){
            Toast.makeText(OfflineGameTable.this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //creating and presenting alert dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialog.setMessage("You Lost!");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
            AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
            dialog.show();
            players[2].setMoney(players[2].getMoney() + Integer.valueOf(tablePot.getText().toString()));
            player3Money.setText(String.valueOf(players[2].getMoney()));
            new CountDownTimer(10000,1000){

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Game();
                }
            }.start();
        }
        if(!players[3].isFolded()){
            Toast.makeText(OfflineGameTable.this, "4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //creating and presenting alert dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialog.setMessage("You Lost!");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
            AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
            dialog.show();
            players[3].setMoney(players[3].getMoney() + Integer.valueOf(tablePot.getText().toString()));
            player4Money.setText(String.valueOf(players[3].getMoney()));
            new CountDownTimer(10000,1000){

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Game();
                }
            }.start();
        }
        if(!players[4].isFolded()){
            Toast.makeText(OfflineGameTable.this, "5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //creating and presenting alert dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialog.setMessage("You Lost!");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
            AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
            dialog.show();
            players[4].setMoney(players[4].getMoney() + Integer.valueOf(tablePot.getText().toString()));
            player5Money.setText(String.valueOf(players[4].getMoney()));
            new CountDownTimer(10000,1000){

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Game();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
}
public void CheckWinner(){
    Toast.makeText(OfflineGameTable.this, "check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    int score1 = CheckHand.checkAllHands(0),score2 = CheckHand.checkAllHands(1),
            score3 = CheckHand.checkAllHands(2),score4 = CheckHand.checkAllHands(3),score5 = CheckHand.checkAllHands(4);

    if(score1 > score2 && score1 > score3 && score1 > score4 && score1 > score5){
        Toast.makeText(OfflineGameTable.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //creating and presenting alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setMessage("You Won!");
        alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
        AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
        dialog.show();
        players[0].setMoney(players[0].getMoney() + Integer.valueOf(tablePot.getText().toString()));
        playerMoney.setText(String.valueOf(players[0].getMoney()));
        new CountDownTimer(10000,1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Game();
            }
        }.start();
    }
    if(score2 > score1 && score2 > score3 && score2 > score4 && score2 > score5){
        Toast.makeText(OfflineGameTable.this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //creating and presenting alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setMessage("You Lost!");
        alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
        AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
        dialog.show();
        players[1].setMoney(players[1].getMoney() + Integer.valueOf(tablePot.getText().toString()));
        player2Money.setText(String.valueOf(players[1].getMoney()));
        new CountDownTimer(10000,1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Game();
            }
        }.start();
    }
    if(score3 > score1 && score3 > score2 && score3 > score4 && score3 > score5){
        Toast.makeText(OfflineGameTable.this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //creating and presenting alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setMessage("You Lost!");
        alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
        AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
        dialog.show();
        players[2].setMoney(players[2].getMoney() + Integer.valueOf(tablePot.getText().toString()));
        player3Money.setText(String.valueOf(players[2].getMoney()));
        new CountDownTimer(10000,1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Game();
            }
        }.start();
    }
    if(score4 > score1 && score4 > score2 && score4 > score3 && score4 > score5){
        Toast.makeText(OfflineGameTable.this, "4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //creating and presenting alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setMessage("You Lost!");
        alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
        AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
        dialog.show();
        players[3].setMoney(players[3].getMoney() + Integer.valueOf(tablePot.getText().toString()));
        player4Money.setText(String.valueOf(players[3].getMoney()));
        new CountDownTimer(10000,1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Game();
            }
        }.start();
    }
    if(score5 > score1 && score5 > score2 && score5 > score3 && score5 > score4){
        Toast.makeText(OfflineGameTable.this, "5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //creating and presenting alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setMessage("You Lost!");
        alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
        AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
        dialog.show();
        players[4].setMoney(players[4].getMoney() + Integer.valueOf(tablePot.getText().toString()));
        player5Money.setText(String.valueOf(players[4].getMoney()));
        new CountDownTimer(10000,1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Game();
            }
        }.start();
    }

}

public void Round(){
    //checking if it's the user's turn
    if(turn%5 == 0&& !players[0].isFolded()){
        Model.enableButtons();
        playersTimer(turn%5);
        played = false;
        //setting a listener to see if the user chose to check/raise/fold
        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Model.confirmCheck();
                played = true;
                turn++;
            }
        });
        raise.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                blankFragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
                blankFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),blankFragment.getTag());

            }
        });
        fold.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                players[0].setFolded(true);
                Model.disableButtons();
                folded ++;
                played = true;
                WinnerByFold();
                turn++;
            }
        });
    }
    else
        turn++;
    //setting a timer for each bot
    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }
        //when the timer finishes, calling a method to make the bot play, repeating this for the rest of the bots
        public void onFinish() {
            new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    ProgressBars[turn%5].setProgress((int)i*100/(10000/1000));
                    i++;
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    ProgressBars[turn%5].setProgress(0);
                    i = 0;
                    botPlay(turn%5);
                    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            ProgressBars[turn%5].setProgress((int)i*100/(10000/1000));
                            i++;
                        }

                        public void onFinish() {
                            ProgressBars[turn%5].setProgress(0);
                            i = 0;
                            botPlay(turn%5);
                            new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    ProgressBars[turn%5].setProgress((int)i*100/(10000/1000));
                                    i++;
                                }

                                public void onFinish() {
                                    ProgressBars[turn%5].setProgress(0);
                                    i = 0;
                                    botPlay(turn%5);
                                    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
                                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                            ProgressBars[turn%5].setProgress((int)i*100/(10000/1000));
                                            i++;
                                        }

                                        public void onFinish() {
                                            ProgressBars[turn%5].setProgress(0);
                                            i = 0;
                                            botPlay(turn%5);
                                        }
                                    }.start();
                                }
                            }.start();
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }.start();
}

final Timer playerTimer = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask;

//making a timer for the user, with progress bar
public void playersTimer(int id){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final boolean[] isFinished = {false};
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TimerCounter ++;
                        ProgressBars[id].setProgress(TimerCounter);
                        //on timer finish, act accordingly
                        if (TimerCounter == 100){
                            if (played == false){
                                players[id].setFolded(true);
                                Model.disableButtons();
                                turn++;
                                Toast.makeText(OfflineGameTable.this, "Folded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            isFinished[0] = true;
                            TimerCounter = 0;
                            ProgressBars[id].setProgress(0);
                            playerTimer.cancel();
                        }

                }
            });
        }
    };
    playerTimer.schedule(timerTask,0,100);
}

//method to send user to lobby activity, presents an alert dialog to confirm
public void backToLobby(View view) {
    //creating and presenting alert dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Exit?");
    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);

    //checking what button the user pressed
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   /* Intent intent = new Intent(OfflineGameTable.this, MainLobby.class);
                    startActivity(intent);*/
                    playerTimer.cancel();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            }
    );
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
    dialog.show();
}


public void handleRaise(){
    if(turn%5 == 0){
        Model.enableButtons();
        playersTimer(turn%5);
        played = false;
        //setting a listener to see if the user chose to check/raise/fold
        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Model.confirmCheck();
                played = true;
            }
        });
        raise.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                blankFragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
                blankFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),blankFragment.getTag());
            }
        });
        fold.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                players[0].setFolded(true);
                Model.disableButtons();
                played = true;
            }
        });
    }
    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            ProgressBars[turn%5].setProgress((int)i*100/(10000/1000));
            i++;
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            ProgressBars[turn%5].setProgress(0);
            i = 0;
            botPlay(turn%5);
            new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    ProgressBars[turn%5].setProgress((int)i*100/(10000/1000));
                    i++;
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    ProgressBars[turn%5].setProgress(0);
                    i = 0;
                    botPlay(turn%5);
                    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            ProgressBars[turn%5].setProgress((int)i*100/(10000/1000));
                            i++;
                        }

                        public void onFinish() {
                            ProgressBars[turn%5].setProgress(0);
                            i = 0;
                            botPlay(turn%5);
                            new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    ProgressBars[turn%5].setProgress((int)i*100/(10000/1000));
                                    i++;
                                }

                                public void onFinish() {
                                    ProgressBars[turn%5].setProgress(0);
                                    i = 0;
                                    botPlay(turn%5);
                                }
                            }.start();
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

}
`

Comment: Did you start OfflineGameTable activity from MainLobby activity? if so, you don't have create it again with intent. you can basically use `finish()` without using intents, and it will let you move to previous activity. but if you have another activities between these two activities, I can share another solution for that. Because your previous activity will be different than main lobby and need to clear your backstack

Comment: Hello Berk Berber, I tried removing the Intent and like you said it sends me to MainLobby but the activity still runs in the background, do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: If you run finish() in your activity, it will be destroyed and you can't see it on back stack anymore. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish()

Can you give more details about how it still runs in the background?

Comment: I have a ``Timer`` that runs for a few seconds and if the player does not play it folds for him and presents a ``Toast`` that says "folded", so the issue is that after I exit the game after a few seconds I see that Toast and when I enter back to a new game my player is folded. Do I need to cancel the Timer somehow for it to work?

Comment: yes, you are probably using CountDownTimer for that. basically, you can add your CountDownTimer into a variable. 

And when you are going to close your OfflineGameTable activity, you can add below code before finish()
```yourCountDownTimer.cancel();```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, also I'm using a Timer and CountDownTimer. If you want I can add the whole activity for you to see.

Comment: yes, that might be more helpful to understand code

Comment: I added it but removed methods that are not important and all imports

Comment: I have tested it by logging and `playerTimer.cancel();` stops the timer task. So, doesn't show. Reason might be it continues to count until you click on Yes button on dialog?

Comment: override `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()` and put logs in them. Observe what's going on after calling `finish()` and 1) whether activity is stopped 2) whether activity is actually destroyed. the `onDestroy()` call isn't actually guaranteed to happen. so lets identify the real problem first. after finishing the activity, hang around in the lobby until the `onDestroy()` log appears.

Comment: Berk Berber `playerTimer.cancel();` works, but I cant cancel the countDownTimer for all the other players so they keep playing.  Shark I will try.

Comment: Shark I tried it and `onDestroy()` log does appear but nothing changed, the activity still runs. it for some reason doesn't cancel all the coundDown Timers.

Comment: you create CountDownTimers with new and don't put them into any variable. So, you need to put each of them to variables and need to cancel them when you don't want them to work anymore